# Use Pandas for interpolation and store time series data with timestamp instead of datetime string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that includes a timestamp column starting from 0.

The first row always starts at time = 0, and the following rows get the relative time from that point. So, e.g. the second row comes 0.25 seconds after the first, obviously it gets the timestamp 0.25.

I want to use the timestamp column mainly for the ability to do resampling and interpolation. So, as far as I know, for that purpose it has to be some time related dtype (`pd.Timestamp` in my case).

Now, what I additionally want, is to be able to save the dataframe as a CSV file afterwards. Unfortunately, the `pd.Timestamp` column is stored as a datetime string of the format

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

I'd however like to save it like it comes in: as a float value starting from 0.0.

I'm thinking about storing the timestamp in the dataframe as two separate columns, one in `pd.Timestamp` format and the other with the same original value as `float`.

Though additionally, data value floats in the frame are stored in the format `%7.3f`. However, the float value of the timestamp should be more precise, rather something like `%.6f` or even more decimal digits. So I'd in addition to all that above need a different float format for a single column.

How can I do all of that together?

Comment: Why not save as a pickle file? Another alternative is making a function to read and write your files, when writing, convert your timestamp to float and when reading convert to float to timestamp.

Comment: Because I save it for another program that demands CSV (or rather TSV, to be more precise) format. And Pandas already has that function to read/write CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Your times sounds more like [`Timedelta`s](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) to me.  You can initialise them as 0, add them together, and then represent them as a float with `pd.Timedelta.total_seconds()`.

```
import pandas as pd
t0 = pd.Timedelta(0)
t1 = t0 + pd.Timedelta('0.25s')

t1_as_float = t1.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Probably can, yes, but I already *have* the stamps as absolute floats. I store the first stamp that comes in and subtract it from the following stamps in order to have the first be 0 and the following be "from that point on". I subsequently convert them to `pd.Timestamp` in order to be able to do resampling on the Dataframe.